io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for left matchers: [any(), any()]
I have the following kotlin code
    val TAG = Logging.tag<MyClass>()
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)

        activitySwitchManagerUtil = ActivitySwitchManagerUtil(activityManager,
            activitySwitchObserverUtil)

        mockkStatic(Log::class)
        every { Log.d(any(), any()) } returns 0
        every { Log.i(any(), any()) } returns 0
        every { Log.e(any(), any()) } returns 0
    }


@Test
    fun `test 1`() {
        ....
        verify {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registered Activity Switch Observer")
        }

    }

Logging.kt
object Logging {
    inline fun <reified T : Any> tag(): String {
        return "$applicationName::${T::class.simpleName}"
    }
}

The above unit test passed until I updated target sdk 28 to 34. The MockK remained the same version. But there were other dependencies I had to update. But it's only when I change target sdk, i see the exception
target sdk = 34
MockK = 1.8.10
Robolectric = 4.12.2;
JDK17 = 1.0;

The exception I'm seeing is
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for

left matchers: [any(), any()]
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.SignatureMatcherDetector.detect(SignatureMatcherDetector.kt:99)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.signMatchers(RecordingState.kt:38)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.round(RecordingState.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.round(CommonCallRecorder.kt:45)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:47)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:25)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:93)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:104)
    at com.company.app.util.MyClassTest.setUp(MyClassTest.kt:37)
    at java.base@17.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.12/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:52)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at app//org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:489)
    at app//org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$2(SandboxTestRunner.java:291)
    at app//org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:104)
    at java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base@17.0.12/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

I tried the following no still running into some kind of error
every { Log.d(any<String>(), any<String>()) } returns 0
every { Log.d(TAG, any<String>()) } returns 0
every { Log.d(TAG, "test") } returns 0



Please end your (otherwise excellent) post with a question.
